# Is boost::variant still used for new projects in the wild?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-variant

It's awful old, copyright 2003. [It lists compatibility with GCC 3.1](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/variant/misc.html#idp496920608), and GCC 5.3 is out now. I want to use it, but I want to make sure it's still being maintained before I use it in my code base.

Comment: My colleague also noted that boost::variant is still being actively maintained! Until other standards are adopted, I think I'll go with boost::variant, since it's easy to sell boost as a dependency. http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_61_0.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost.Variant is still useable, but like you say, it's showing its age. It's a C++98 library, so it emulates variadic templates, which means there's an upper limit on the number of options you can have in one variant. It also requires visitors to inherit from `boost::static_visitor`, which is annoying. But if you're still stuck with C++98 then it's probably still the best option there is.

For C++11/14 projects, I'd recommend using [eggs.variant](https://github.com/eggs-cpp/variant) or [this impementation of `std::experimental::variant`](https://bitbucket.org/anthonyw/variant) (which will likely be part of C++17).

Comment: for C++14 you can supply a generic lambda as a visitor (scroll down to the bottom here: https://meetingcpp.com/index.php/br/items/boostvariant-and-a-general-generic-visitor-class.html)

Comment: looks like `eggs::variant` does not support storing references, a feature I often need and `boost::variant` provides